# Adobe AIR and multiple XMLHttpRequests is being... weird

Tags: javascript, ajax, air, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a small Adobe AIR app (my first) using HTML+Javascript. I need to run more than one asynchronous data request, but the second one didn't seem to be firing (note that the requests were not run concurrently originally). I tried stripping the program down to the bare minimum that exhibited problems, and at first only the first request fired, but then things got strange. Code and output follows:

```
<html> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AIRAliases.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        function download(page) {
            var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=xml&page=" + page;
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    air.trace("Done");
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }

        function appLoad() { 
            download("Main Page");
            download("Main Page");
        }  
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="appLoad()"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Expected output:

```
Done
Done
```

Actual output:

```
C:\AIRSDK\apps\HelloWorld>adl HelloWorld-app.xml
Done
C:\AIRSDK\apps\HelloWorld>adl HelloWorld-app.xml
Done
C:\AIRSDK\apps\HelloWorld>adl HelloWorld-app.xml
Done
C:\AIRSDK\apps\HelloWorld>adl HelloWorld-app.xml
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
```

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old thread but I'm trying to do an asynch xmlhttprequest but get no responseText or responseXML in my readystatechange function. It's only called once with status set to 0 and readystate of 4. In your code it says done but where and how do you store the content of the page? Here is the example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155112/unable-to-get-response-status-from-adobe-air-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Note that on Windows AIR uses IE so when my IE was set to work offline I had strange things happen with the request. Some were ok as they were in cache and some would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, you shouldn't re-use xmlhttprequest objects (even if you don't realise you are because you're a complete noob at Javascript).

This line:

```
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Should be:

```
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```