# Unable to get response status from adobe air xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, air, xmlhttprequest

This is the code in the html/javascrpt file:

```
var console = console || 
    {log:function(msg){window.runtime.trace(msg);}};
function waitToFinish(){
    console.log("this is wait to finish loading the url");
    console.log(this.readyState);
    console.log(this.status);
    if(this.readyState != 4){
        return;
    }
    console.log("readystate is 4");
    console.log("response text length is:"+this.responseText.length);
    if (this.status === 200 || this.status == 304) { // status is allways 0
        console.log("success");
        console.log("response text length is:"+this.responseText.length);
    }
}
function openURL(url){
    console.log("opening link:"+url);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url 
            ,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
        =waitToFinish;
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    return false; 
<input type=button onclick="openURL('http://www.yahoo.com');" value="click me" />
}
```

Here is the output in air:

```
opening link:http://www.yahoo.com
this is wait to finish loading the url
4
0
readystate is 4
response text length is:0
```

This is the output in firefox with forcecors plugin activated:

```
opening link:http://www.yahoo.com
GET http://www.yahoo.com/ 200 OK        4.3s    
this is wait to finish loading the url
1
0
this is wait to finish loading the url
2
200
this is wait to finish loading the url
... a bunch of times readystate change is called
this is wait to finish loading the url
4
200
readystate is 4
response text length is:317163
success
response text length is:317163
```

In air onreadystate is called once and that's it, state is immediately 4 but status stays 0 and responseText is empty.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb3.html

Shows an example for xmlhttprequest checking only for readystate but if I do that the responseText is empty all the time every time. Synchronyous requests work but async doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows AIR uses IE so when my IE was set to work offline I had strange things happen with the request. Some were ok as they were in cache and some would fail.

Set IE to work online and everything was working "normal" again.